# Adding a socket descriptor to the io_service dynamically and removing it

Tags: sockets, network-programming, boost-asio

I am writing a gateway service which listens on the network socket and routes the packets received to separate daemons. I am planning to use boost asio but I am stuck with few questions. Here is the design of the server I am planning to implement:

1. The gateway will be listening for TCP connections using boost asio.
2. The gateway will also listen for streamed Unix domain connections from daemons using boost asio.
3. Whenever there is a packet on the tcp connection the gateway looks at the protocol tag in the packet and puts the packet on the unix domain connection on which the service will is listening.
4. Whenever there is a packet on the service connection the gateway looks at the client tag and puts on the respective client connection.

Every descriptor in the gateway will be a NONBLOCKING one.

I am stuck with one particular problem, when the gateway is writing to the service connection, there are chances of getting an EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK error if the service socket is full. I plan to tackle this by queuing the buffers and "waiting for the service connection get ready for write".

If I were to use select system call "waiting for the service connection get ready for write" would translate to adding the fd in the writefd list and passing it to select. Once the service connection is ready for write I will write the enqueued buffers to the connection and will remove the service connection from the writefdlist of select.

How do i do the same thing with boost asio? Is such thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with that approach, then use [`boost::asio::null_buffers`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html) to enable [Reactor-Style operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html).  Additionally, set the Boost.Asio socket to non-blocking through the [`socket::non_blocking()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/non_blocking/overload2.html) member function.  This option will set the synchronous socket operations to be non-blocking.  This is different from setting the native socket as non-blocking, as Boost.Asio sets the native socket as non-blocking, and emulates blocking for synchronous operations.

However, if Proactor-Style operations are an option, then consider using them, as it allows the application to ignore some of the lower level details.  When using proactor style operations, Boost.Asio will perform the I/O on the application's behalf, properly handling `EWOULDBLOCK`, `EAGAIN`, and `ERROR_RETRY` logic.  For example, when Boost.Asio incurs one of the previously mentioned errors, it pushes the I/O operation back into its internal queue, deferring its reattempt, allowing other operations to be attempted.

Often times, there are two constraints which require the use of Reactor-Style operations instead of Proactor-Style operations:

- Another library expects to perform the I/O operations itself.
- Memory limitations.  With a Proactor, the lifespan of a buffer must exceed the duration of a read or write operation, and concurrent operations may require their own buffer.  A Reactor allows for the lifetime of a buffer to begin when data is ready to be read, and end when data is no longer being used.

Comment: +1 nice summary or reasons why the reactor pattern may be necessary

Answer (score 1):

Using boost::asio you dont need to mess with nonblocking mode and/or with return codes such as EAGAIN EWOULDBLOCK etc. Also, you are not "adding a socket to pool loop" or something like that; this is hidden for you since it more highlevel framework.

Typical pattern is

1. You create io_service object
2. You create socket with binding to io_service
3. You create some async event (async_connect, async_read, async_write or so on) on the socket.
4. You run dispatching with io_service::run or similar methods.
5. asio will trigger your handler when time is come.

Check out for [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) on the boost::asio page. I think [async echo server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) can illustrate technique for your task.

Comment: I agree, i should not care about EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK thats what asio is for right, but wouldnt the write_handler will be continously invoke because a socket will always be ready to write ? in my case the service connection here will always be ready to write and resulting in a busy loop.

Comment: @RavikumarTulugu no. Handlers will be invoked when job is done or its completely failed (e.g. canceled or peer disconnected). After your write_handler invoked, asio will forget about it, since write job is done. When you need to write next block of data, you will need to call async_write again. So, handler is not called when you CAN write, its called when asio finished with your task.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple threads will be writing to the same socket object used for a connection, then you need to use a mutex (or critical section if using Windows) to single thread the code.

As for - "when the gateway is writing to the service connection, there are chances of getting an EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK error if the service socket is full", I believe that ASIO handles that for you internally so you don't have to worry about it.